# how to print a section of each line of a file in c

Tags: c, file, file-io, scanf

i have a text file that has a layout like this on each line:

```
66.249.66.146 - - [31/Jul/2011:12:06:57 +0100] "GET /issue-download/page/4/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3768 "-"
```

where:

```
IP address - - <some extra stuff>
```

i'm trying to only print the IP address using:

```
while (fgets(singleLine, 14, file) != NULL) {
    if (strncmp(singleLine, "66.249.66", 9) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", singleLine);
    }
}
```

but of course, the first 13 characters of each line isn't always the IP address and if the IP address was something like `66.249.66.5`, it'll print as `66.249.66.5 -`

i tried doing an fscanf method, so:

```
char ip[14];
char extra[100];

fscanf(file, "%s - - %s", &ip, &extra);

while (fgets(singleLine, 14, file) != NULL) {
    if (strncmp(singleLine, "66.249.66", 9) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", ip);
    }
}
```

as well as `%d.%d.%d.%d` with fscanf to represent the IP but that doesn't work also. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @user3121023 they all have an IP address at the start

Comment: @user3121023 yeah, it always starts with digits

Comment: Your fscanf code shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how computers work. Did you know that the computer does one thing at a time, in the order the code tells them to?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this after reading each lines:

1. Search for the separator via `strstr()`.
2. Compute the number of elements between the beginning of the data and the separator found.
3. Use the number to specify the number of characters to print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char data[] = "66.249.66.146 - - [31/Jul/2011:12:06:57 +0100] \"GET /issue-download/page/4/ HTTP/1.1\" 200 3768 \"-\"";
    char* separator;
    int length;
    separator = strstr(data, " - - ");
    if (separator != NULL) {
        length = separator - data;
        printf("%.*s\n", length, data);
    } else {
        puts("(invalid format)");
    }
    return 0;
}
```